# Update 1 or many fields in django model without if else condition statement

Tags: python, django

I currently have the following code:

HTTP/POST

```
------WebKitFormBoundary2s9CNLxw7qrgzD94
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="first_name"

Mike
```

forms.py

```
class TenantUpdateForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Tenant
        fields = ["first_name", "last_name", "email", "birthday", "stars", "company",
              "position", "client_type", "phone", "identification", "comments"]
```

views.py

```
@csrf_exempt
@jwt_authentication
@require_http_methods(["POST"])
def update_tenant(request, unique_key):

    instance = get_object_or_404(Tenant, unique_key=unique_key)
    form = TenantUpdateForm(request.POST, instance=instance)

    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        payload = {"status": True,
                "description": "Tenant fields updated."}

        return HttpResponse(json.dumps(payload, indent=2, cls=json_encoder),
                            content_type='application/json',
                            status=200)
    else:
        payload = {"status": False,
                "description": "Form is invalid.",
                "form": form.errors.as_json()}

        return HttpResponse(json.dumps(payload, indent=2, cls=json_encoder),
                            content_type='application/json',
                            status=404)
```

So far everything works fine. But When I try to update just a single field it it changes the field but all the other fields go blank.

Comment: How are you changing just one field?  By only filling in one field in the form?

Comment: Also, please post the code to your `TenantUpdateForm`.  If you're trying to do what I expect you're trying to do, the solution will be to update that form.

Comment: Just updated the question with more code. @2ps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default behavior for the django form is to update all fields of the model.  When they're not filled out, they will come back as `None` or `''` and update the model that way.  If you want to change that behavior, you'll have to roll some additional code in your `save` function.  Here's what I would try:

```
from django.db import models

class TenantUpdateForm(ModelForm):
    def _post_clean(self):
        # intentionally override parent post-clean
        # it will overwrite our instance
        pass

    def save(commit=True):
        if not self.instance:
            # delegate to super class for creates, 
            # we only want to affect updates.
            return super(TenantUpdateForm, self).save(commit)
        for key in self.data.keys():      
            try:
                self.instance._meta.get_field(key)              
                value = self.cleaned_data[key]
                setattr(self.instance, key, value)
            except KeyError:
                pass
        if commit:
            self.instance.save()
        return self.instance   

    class Meta:
        model = Tenant
        fields = ["first_name", "last_name", "email", "birthday", "stars", "company",
              "position", "client_type", "phone", "identification", "comments"]
```

Note that there is a trade-off with this approach:  the user cannot null out a field using this form; however, the form will work the way that you want by just updating one field of the instance.  The typical approach with such forms is to pass the instance to the form being used to render the form on `get`ter view so that old fields show up in the rendered form that the user is submitting to this `post` view.  That way all fields are resubmitted with the form unless the user intentionally deletes them.

Comment: Thanks, your solution helped me to do the intended action. Just needed to add self ( def save(self, commit=True) to the function.

Comment: there is a way to tell if a user send s wrong form field example: my_planet. So the save() method wont crash because the field its not being found in the for loop.

Comment: Just use the `_meta.get_field` on the instance to see if the field is valid.

Comment: Code has been updated to handle the field not being found.